# npm run command not working after git clone

Tags: npm, git-clone

Every time I created new git clone, the following npm run command is not working. Anyone faced any issue with it?

I need to go through npm install command.

Comment: In most cases you'll need to install the dependencies before running the scripts that rely on them, yes.

Comment: That is good point. I remember getting dependencies error. However not able to fix it? What the dependencies need to be considered and how to install it? Any input appreciated

Comment: You install them with the install command you mention _in your question_, so I'm not sure what the problem is.